# Two view controllers being instantiated on start up

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have a storyboard with 2 View controllers and 1 Navigation View Controller.

It looks like:

1VC
1Navigation-VC--->2VC

The first View Controller is the one created by Xcode when you select "1 single view App" and it was the entry point for the app.

Now I have created the Navigation Controller and the second view controller attached to it. I have changed the entry point, so now the App starts up with that Navigation Controller.

Everything works fine, but the first View Controller is also being instantiated(but not shown) at start up (I use NSLog() in -viewDidLoad). I don´t know why this is happening, because the first VC is right now not connected to anything and the entry point for that VC is deactivated.

Do somebody knows why is that happening?

Thanks!

Screenshot SB:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY6C9.png

And for the Nav Controller :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTlID.png

I have also tried overriding the:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

     UINavigationController *viewController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myStoryboard1"];



    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It's probably still created in the AppDelegate. try to delete the first view controller from your project and see which error you get ;-).

Comment: can you give screenshot of your story board

Comment: can u paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized what was happening. My first scene uses a View Controller class called "ViewController". When I created the second VC instead of extend from UIViewController, I typed ViewController.

Novice mistake.

Thank you anyways. ;)